# How to transform Function Application settings of Azure Function App .NET core 2.0 in DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing serverless function on .NET core runtime 2.0 using Visual Studio 2019, where I am using App Service Settings for local + remote testing in Azure, but I can't find a way how to transform these settings in DevOps Pipeline so I can deploy it with production settings to production resource group in Azure. Is there any way how to do that, or am I doing it wrong? Sadly, somehow I can't find my answers on Google...

Is there someone who can help me with it?

Comment: “Is there someone who can help me?” [is not a question we can answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: Nice to see that you have already prepared this phrase in clipboard... I think there is no space to be polite. Anyway. Since .net core 2.0 function app doesn't have any kind of remote settings in solution, so I can't do it with substitution I used before, but another way I can't find... How can I do this with .net core 2.0 function app? I hope this question is good enough

Comment: You could use an ARM template to deploy the settings (or from the Portal). That way the code you deploy using the pipeline is independent of the environment into which you deploy it. You can also encrypt the settings and pull them from a key-vault.

Comment: This is perfect, I will go with that ARM template. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops ?

Scroll down to **JSON variable substitution** section

Comment: Yeah I saw this, but since I can't find that json file in solution, I don't think this is possible. I was searching even in release package, but it's not there. Also in Publish in projects it takes too long, so I'm afraid it's not stored like usual json file. All I can see it local.settings.json, where are just local keys of my settings